# How exactly is user informed about deleting answer from review queue?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

In low quality queue, I can vote for deleting an answer. I can choose the reason, for example 'It should be a comment' or 'It's mee too answer'. Those reasons are converted into comments.

However, if the answer is eventually deleted (and as I understand, that's the idea of the review queue), the comments are deleted too.

What notification exactly users become when their answer is deleted? Do they become a notification with delete reason, or such delete reason is 'forgotten'?

My consideration is, if choosing the correct delete reason really provides a feedback to the OP. Otherwise, I could use 'no comment needed' reason as well...

Comment: No notification. Like with any other comment, if the user clicked the inbox to see the comment before the post was deleted it will stay in the inbox for good but otherwise no special notification.

Comment: They can also access their recently deleted answers through the "deleted recent answers" link in their profile... they'd then be able to see the comments you left on a particular post. This however, is something the user has to poll for feedback, rather than being notified when a post of theirs has been deleted.

Comment: The comments are **not** deleted. They are still there when you visit the answer (and the OP can still see the post when they do).

Comment: The comment notification will also still be visible in the inbox; because the OP can see the deleted answer, the comments are still visible to them so the inbox notification is still present too.

Comment: Last but not least, don't assume everyone will vote to delete; your comment could be up for a prolonged amount of time. If there is an applicable comment, please do pick it. I only ever use 'no comment required' when I already put in a custom comment or the post is obvious spam.

Comment: @Martijn: Are you saying the inbox message will persist, even if the user didn't open their inbox and view the message before the answer was deleted? If so, this contradicts what Sha said; any ideas which is the correct behaviour?

Comment: @Matt: In my experience my inbox still shows me messages on posts that have been deleted. I could remember that wrong though.

Comment: @Martijn: I really don't know. I'd prefer that behaviour, but I'd be interested to know what *actually* happens!

Comment: I self-deleted a question a couple of days ago, and Shog commented on it post-delete and I got the notification. So Martijn is almost certainly correct.